# Equivalent of Iron Router's pathFor in Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, iron-router, angular-meteor

In Meteor's Iron Router, we could use `pathFor` to generate a URL, such as

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'posts' id=1234}}">View</a>
```

can generate the URL `http://domain.com/posts/1234`.

**Question:** Using Angular's UI Router, is there an equivalent of `pathFor`?

Such that with the routes defined below, we can generate the URL `http://domain.com/posts/1234` by having something similar to `{{ pathFor 'posts' id=1234}}`.

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('posts', {
            url: '/posts/:postId',
            templateUrl: 'client/posts/views/post.html',
            controller: 'PostCtrl'
        })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :

```
<a ui-sref="posts({postId:1234})">View</a>
```

where `posts` is the state name.

See [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

**ADDITIONAL**

To get the value of `postId` and use it on your controller you can use `resolve` like this.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('posts', {
        url: '/posts/:postId',
        templateUrl: 'client/posts/views/post.html',
        controller: 'PostCtrl',
        resolve: {
            ID : function($stateParams){
                return $stateParams.postId;
            }
        }
    })
```

Then inject the `ID` to your controller.

```
.controller('PostCtrl',
    ['$scope', 'ID', function($scope, ID){
        // you now have the access to ID
        $scope.id = ID;
}])
```